# JSON call fails under IIS

Tags: json, iis

we are using Joomla on Windows hosting, and we have a developed e-commerce using eShop

suddenly, simply hitting the "register" button in eshop gives a "Internal Server Error" alert triggered by eShop component...

here's partial code of what the eShop component does...

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo EshopHelper::getSiteUrl(); ?>index.php?option=com_eshop&task=checkout.login',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#checkout-options #login :input'),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-login').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#button-login').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="components/com_eshop/assets/images/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
            },  
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-login').attr('disabled', false);
                $('.wait').remove();
            },              
            success: function(json) {
                $('.warning, .error').remove();
                if (json['return']) {
                    window.location.href = json['return'];
                } else if (json['error']) {
                    $('#checkout-options .checkout-content').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '</div>');
                    $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

( the last row triggers the error...)

What could have gone worng?

Comment: No, the last line is where the error is handled on the *client side*. The error happens *on the server side* and your JavaScript has nothing to do with it.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, the last line of code returns the error to the client...

Comment: looks like this is te page giving the error:

http://www.doggyhair.it/index.php?option=com_eshop&task=checkout.login&lang=it

Comment: Talk to the people that run doggyhair.it. We cannot fix their broken server.

Comment: what a pointless answer...we are the ones running the website (not me personally) and I cannot figure what went wrong...

Comment: There are two possibilities here: 1) My answer was pointless. 2) You did not understand it. To find out, read my first comment again.

Comment: nevermind. I am obviously looking server-side

Comment: Obviously you are not, because the code you show has nothing to do with the error you receive.

Comment: this was to show what is being called when I click the button, make the JSON call and get the server error...

json calls index.php?option=com_eshop&task=checkout.login and there's the generic Internal Server Error ....I am checking every log on the server with no luck. I was simply asking for advice on possible causes...

Comment: And I would like to give you that advice, but you need to debug the `index.php` or the PHP/IIS integration or file system rights or application pools or any number of possible reasons. "500 internal server error" really isn't enough to go on.

Comment: SOLVED:

I worked with our system engineer to solve the problem...
it turns out that php errors were not logged on the server.

or better:
**log_error** in php.ini was ON
but **error_log**  was pointing to a non-existant path...


I asked him to create the required folders and Bingo! php error log magically appeared and "Syntax Error: unexpected '}' found at line 61 in xxxxx.php"

2 second to fix it, 3 days to find out.... grrrrr

Comment: ...and as I said in the beginning, the code you show in your question has nothing to do with your problem. ;)

Comment: yes, it was in the controller file being called....somewhere in between the code I posted and the index.php page. But the server wasn't giving out enough information to diagnose the problem...

Comment: Next time it would be great if you were not so quick with dismissing a comment with "what a pointless answer".